# Zend: Fatal error: Constructor Zend\Stdlib\Glob::glob() cannot be static

Tags: php, xampp, zend-framework2

I'm using XAMPP on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and I'm just setting up my first Zend application and tried setting up the Skeleton Application, followed all the steps in the manual but keep getting: `Fatal error: Constructor Zend\Stdlib\Glob::glob() cannot be static in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/Glob.php on line 193`

I've googled for this problem and came back with an old version of php, but when i terminal php -v from the skeleton application's directory I get:

```
PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2010 12:15:07) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
bens-imac:zf2-tutorial Ben$
```

So i don't get what the problem could be, any ideas?

Comment: there is no specific code to share, just typing in the url of my skeleton application into the browser and that's what i get

Comment: Have you read these two issues? http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-432 and http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-542 In the former the issues was caused by an upgrade of OSX. In the latter the solution was to switch from XAMPP to MAMP.

Comment: there the problem is a php version that is too old, but i'm running 5.3.4 so it should work

Comment: Can you open `public/index.php` and add `phpinfo()` to it? Preferably as first line. There may be two PHP Versions on your system.

Comment: you're right sam... how do i point my xampp apache to the right php?

Comment: @BenGreene I'd say, simply uninstall the current XAMPP and install the newest version ^^

Comment: thanks, i was using the latest version, i ditched xampp alltogether and set up everything manually

Answer (score 2):

What version of PHP are you using? This should not be an issue for PHP versions 5.3.3 and up...
I've tried on 5.3.3, 5.3.11, and 5.4.1, and have no errors. :)